# My selenium code doesn't work on IE 11

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have some automation tests using Java-Selenium working fine with Chrome/Firefox/IE9. I have Selenium 2.47 and using appropriate driver exes. Recently I had upgraded to IE 11 and since then my tests are failing with following exception:

```
*org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to find elements on closed window (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)*
Command duration or timeout: 31 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, pageLoadStrategy=normal, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreZoomSetting=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:13059/, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
*** Element info: {Using=name, value=username}
```

Can someone guide me on this?

Its failing at login page itself.

Comment: Need More information bro.

Comment: This is the line where this exception is thrown: webElements = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(byType));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an issue with IE11 and selenium. You need to configure IE11 in Windows registry in order to fix the issue.

To work around the issue, create a DWORD value with the name "iexplore.exe" and the
value of 0 in the following key (for 32-bit Windows):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE
```

For 64-bit Windows installations, the following key should be used:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE
```

This will work around "Unable to get browser" errors and should
resolve the unsupported issues with IE11.

Comment: If you're going to just steal others' writing without attribution, you could at least change the first-person comments. You, answerer, are not going to update the project wiki, because I, the actual author of the text above, did so [more than two years ago](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/6511).